# what will happen if I change the __name__ of a function

Tags: python

I'm a beginner of python. I learned a function has properties named `__name__` and `__qualname__`, and they are writable.

I changed the value of **name** and **qualname**. eg,

```
def person(name):
print(name)

person.__name__ = 'man'
person.__qualname__ = 'man'
```

then I tried to call `man('jessi')`, the interpreter reported `name 'man' is not defined`.
so my question is, what's the meaning of change the value of  `__name__`
Thank you in advance anyway

Comment: There are various uses, such making a wrapper from a decorator look the same as the wrapped function, e.g. using `functools.wraps`. But there's a lot of concepts there that would need to be unpacked carefully for a beginner. For now, don't worry about it.

Comment: Note that `def person(name):` syntax does two things: it creates a function object named `person` **and** creates a variable `person` with the function assigned to it. When you change `person.__name__` you just modify the function object. It doesn't affect the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of `__name__` changes the representation of the function, not its functionality. Observe:

```
>>> def person(name):
...     print(name)
... 
>>> person.__name__
'person'
>>> print(person)
<function person at 0x10030bc08>
>>> person.__name__ = 'man'
>>> print(person)
<function man at 0x10030bc08>
```

Note that this only happens with Python 2.7 - In Python 3, you'd use `.__qualname__` instead. The same behaviour occurs with `__qualname__`:

```
>>> def person(name):
...     def child():
...             return 'Hello child of ' + name
...     return child
>>> result = person("Me!")
>>> print(result)
<function person.<locals>.child at 0x103b45048>
>>> result.__qualname__
'person.<locals>.child'
>>> result.__name__
'child'
>>> result.__qualname__ = 'new qualname result'
>>> result.__qualname__
'new qualname result'
>>> print(result)
<function new qualname result at 0x101bb6e18>
```

Comment: It is writeable in Python, it just doesn't do anything. `__qualname__` is what's used for the representation in Python 3.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6.4, ```.__name__``` is still writable. Are there any cases that we need to change the representation of a function?

Comment: @lwiu Only visually/cosmetically, otherwise no practical use (that I know of...)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Sorry - yes - what I mean is that it's writeable in the sense that you can assign something to it but nothing changes

Comment: @lwiu I doubt there's ever a reason to do that. In fact this makes debuging more difficult which is a serious disadvantage. And I don't see any benefit from doing that.

Comment: @freakish Wrapper functions are the only exception I can think of, but usually you should just use `functools.wraps` rather than manually overwriting the value.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I don't see any reason for wrappers to change functions' names. Making it the same as the underlying function makes it confusing when you debug stuff. You no longer know whether the error comes from your inner function or the wrapper itself.

Comment: If you're using a decorator to wrap a function, it's way less confusing if you rename the function. For example [here](https://pastebin.com/Ygg27Jae), when you do `print(foo)`, would you rather see `<function wrapper at 0x1234>` or `<function foo at 0x1234>`?